# python regex to return empty string

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract part of a string in a list which does not have a space followed by number in python.

```
# INPUT
text = ['bits', 'scrap 1.2', 'bits and pieces', 'junk 3.4.2']
# EXPECTED OUTPUT
output = ['bits', 'scrap', 'bits and pieces', 'junk']
```

I managed to do this using re.sub or re.split:

```
output = [re.sub(" [0-9].*", "", t) for t in text]
# OR
output = [re.split(' \d',t)[0] for t in text]
```

When I tried to use re.search and re.findall, it return me empty list or empty result.

```
[re.search('(.*) \d', t) for t in text]
#[None, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='scrap 1'>, None, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='junk 3'>]

[re.findall('(.*?) \d', t) for t in text]
#[[], ['scrap'], [], ['junk']]
```

Can anyone help me with the regex that can return expected output for re.search and re.findall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may remove the digit-and-dot substrings at the end of the string only with

```
import re
text = ['bits', 'scrap 1.2', 'bits and pieces', 'junk 3.4.2']
print([re.sub(r'\s+\d+(?:\.\d+)*$', '', x) for x in text])
# => output = ['bits', 'scrap', 'bits and pieces', 'junk']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xb3k97)

The pattern is

- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (note: if those digits can be "glued" to some other text, replace `+` (one or more occurrences) with `*` quantifier (zero or more occurrences))
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/1BNTtX/2).

**To do the same with `re.findall`**, you can use

```
# To get 'abc 5.6 def' (not 'abc') from 'abc 5.6 def 6.8.9'
re.findall(r'^(.*?)(?: \d[\d.]*)?$', x) # 
# To get 'abc' (not 'abc 5.6 def') from 'abc 5.6 def 6.8.9'
re.findall(r'^(.*?)(?: \d.*)?$', x) #
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gttQdO/2/).

However, this regex is not efficient enough due to the `.*?` construct. Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars (use `re.DOTALL` to match all) as few as possible (so that the next optional group could be tested at each position)
- `(?: \d[\d.]*)?` -an optional non-capturing group matching

  - - a space
  - `\d` - a digit
  - `[\d.]*` - zero or more digits or `.` chars
  - (OR) `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I can do it with `re.sub`. I can't do it with `re.search` or `re.findall`

Comment: re.sub is faster than `re.findall` with `(.*?)` ? What is it with `.*?` construct since I use it a lot in my python codes.

Comment: @addicted I added a `re.findall` compatible regex to the answer. The `.*?` is a lazily quantified dot, it matches in a way opposite to backtracking: it is skipped first, then the rest of the subsequent subpatterns are tried. If they fail, the `.*?` matches the first char where it was supposed to be tested, and then again all the subsequent subpatterns are tried, etc. In effect, the match is found much slower than it could be **if** the match is far to the right from the first `.*?` matching location. On the other hand, `.*` would cause backtracking issues in the opposite situation.

Comment: @addicted Are you asking what the question mark means in this context?

Comment: @Arne if i am not wrong, the `?` means 'not greedy' or match only once or none

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the explanation. Btw your first `re.findall` regex strings fit my case better ie. `re.search(r'^(.*?)(?: \d.*)?$', x)`. The recently edited one does not work for me.

Comment: @addicted That is probably because you want to get `abc`  (not `abc 5.6 def`) from `abc 5.6 def 6.8.9`. I added a variation of the regex back.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Got it. Thanks. I have 1 more question if you don't mind. Say if re.search or re.findall cannot find the specified string, can they return empty string ie. `''` or list of empty string `['']` instead of empty list `[]` or `None`?

Comment: @addicted No, these methods output cannot be changed. Use extra programming logic to get the type of result you need. `re.findall` will always return `[]` if nothing is found and `re.search` only returns `None` upon no match.